# Adding trusted timestamps to Git commits

Tags: beginner, bash, git, openssl

I don't write too many bash scripts and I can usually struggle my way through getting the odd thing I need working, but my scripts always seem to feel a bit brittle.  Below is a script I wrote for adding trusted timestamps to commits in a Git repository.  I would appreciate any feedback on ways I could improve it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit immediately if any commands return non-zero
set -e

# Config variables.
url=<use a URL to an RFC3161 service>
cafile="${HOME}/time-stamping-cert-chain.crt"
request_delay=15 # COMODO asks for this in scripts.
blobref="tsa-blobs" # tsa = time stamp authority

# Make sure the script was called from within a Git repo.  Ignore
# stdout.
git rev-parse --show-toplevel > /dev/null

# Start with flags set to false
delay_next=false
verbose=false
ltime=false

prep() {
    # Assume we start with no note.
    note=false

    # The revision should be the first argument.
    rev="$1"

    # If no revision is specified, assume HEAD.
    if [ -z "$rev" ]; then
        rev="HEAD"
    fi

    # Run git rev-parse since it will expand HEAD and shortend hashes for
    # us.
    rev="$(git rev-parse "$rev")"

    # Figure out if the timestamp note exists.
    git notes --ref="$blobref" show "$rev" > /dev/null 2>&1 && note=true \
        || true # Make sure the command exits 0
}

print_rev() {
    if $verbose; then
        echo "$rev"
    else
        echo "$(git rev-parse --short "$rev")"
    fi
}

print_signed_timestamp() {
    tsatime="$(echo "$1" | grep -i "time stamp:" | cut -c13-)"
    echo -e "\t$(date -d "$tsatime" +"SIGNED-%d-%b-%Y")"
    #echo "$(date -d "$tsatime" --iso-8601=minutes)"
    #echo "$(date -d "$tsatime" +"%Y-%m-%d-%T-%Z")"
}

print_local_timestamp() {
    if $ltime; then
        ctime="$(git log --pretty=format:"%ad" --date=iso "$rev" -1)"
        echo -e "\t$(date -d "$ctime" +"COMMITTED-%d-%b-%Y")"
    fi
}

# This outputs the text version of the TSA reply for the current
# revision.
examine() {
    if $note; then
        timestamp="$(git notes --ref="$blobref" show "$rev")"
        text="$(echo "$timestamp" | openssl enc -d -base64 | openssl ts -reply -in /dev/stdin -text)"

        echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
        echo "Revision: ${rev}$(print_local_timestamp)"
        echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
        echo "$text"
        echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    else
        echo "$(print_rev)$(print_local_timestamp)\tNo trusted timestamp."
    fi
}

# This loads the TSA reply for the current revision from git notes,
# re-verifies it, and outputs short info about the verified timestamp.
verify() {
    if ! $note; then
        echo -e "$(print_rev)$(print_local_timestamp)\tNo trusted timestamp."
        return 0
    fi

    timestamp="$(git notes --ref="$blobref" show "$rev")"
    text="$(echo "$timestamp" | openssl enc -d -base64 | openssl ts -reply -in /dev/stdin -text)"
    echo "$timestamp" | openssl enc -d -base64 \
        | openssl ts -verify -digest "$rev" -in /dev/stdin -CAfile "$cafile"  > /dev/null 2>&1

    echo -e "$(print_rev)$(print_local_timestamp)$(print_signed_timestamp "$text")"
}

# This creates a note for the current revision and verifies it.  If the
# verification is successful, the reply is base64 encoded and stored
# in the $ref namespace of git notes for the current revision.  After
# storing the note, it is re-loaded, un-coded, and re-verified before
# outputting short info about the verified timestamp.
create() {
    if $note; then
        verify
        return 0
    fi

    # Wait for the delay requested by the timestamp service.
    if $delay_next; then
        sleep $request_delay
    fi

    # Content-type and Accept type need to be included in the request header
    # when connecting to the timestamp service.
    CONTENT_TYPE="Content-Type: application/timestamp-query"
    ACCEPT_TYPE="Accept: application/timestamp-reply"

    # Create the timestamp request using the specified revision as a digest.  The
    # sha1 hashes Git uses for revisions are already in the correct format.  The
    # default should be sha1, but we specify it anyway to show our intent is to
    # pass an sha1 hash.
    #
    # The request is submitted to the timestamp server using curl.
    #
    # The data is base64 encoded and temporarily stored in the TSREPLY variable so
    # the timestamp can be verified before storing it in Git notes.
    timestamp=$(openssl ts -query -cert -digest "$rev" -sha1 \
        | curl -s -H "$CONTENT_TYPE" -H "$ACCEPT_TYPE" --data-binary @- "$url" \
        | openssl enc -base64)

    # Verify the reply to make sure the timestamp is valid.  We don't want to add
    # invalid timestamps to Git notes since an invalid timestamp has no value.
    echo "$timestamp" \
        | openssl enc -d -base64 \
        | openssl ts -verify -digest "$rev" -in /dev/stdin -CAfile "$cafile"  > /dev/null 2>&1

    # Put the base64 encoded blob into the $BLOBblobref namespace.
    echo "$timestamp" | git notes --ref="$blobref" add "$rev" --file -

    # Perform a sanity check to make sure we can re-verify the
    # timestamp using the blob we just added to the $blobref
    # namespace.
    git notes --ref="$blobref" show "$rev" | openssl enc -d -base64 \
        | openssl ts -verify -digest "$rev" -in /dev/stdin -CAfile "$cafile"  > /dev/null 2>&1

    # Get the text version of the reply
    text="$(echo "$timestamp" | openssl enc -d -base64 | openssl ts -reply -in /dev/stdin -text)"

    echo -e "$(print_rev)$(print_local_timestamp)$(print_signed_timestamp "$text") (CREATED)"
    delay_next=true
}

# This removes the verified timestamp for the current revision.
remove() {
    if ! $note; then
        echo -e "$(print_rev)$(print_local_timestamp)\tNo trusted timestamp. Skipping."
        return 0
    fi

    git notes --ref="$blobref" remove "$rev" > /dev/null 2>&1

    echo -e "$(print_rev)$(print_local_timestamp)\tTrusted timestamp removed."
}

push() {
    git push "origin" "refs/notes/${blobref}"
}

fetch() {
    git fetch "origin" "refs/notes/${blobref}:refs/notes/${blobref}"
}

# Script logic starts below here.

# Check for very basic switches, mainly to output detailed information
# about the timestamp.
while getopts ":vlh" opt; do
  case $opt in
    v)
      verbose=true
      ;;
    l)
      ltime=true
      ;;
    h)
      echo "Usage: git-timestamp [options] command [revision]" >&2
      echo
      echo " options"
      echo "  -h - Show this usage info.  All other options are ignored."
      echo "  -v - Output long revision instead of short."
      echo "  -l - Also show the local commit time of the specified revision."
      echo
      echo " command"
      echo "  create  - Create a timestamp. Revisions with existing timestamps will be"
      echo "            verified instead."
      echo "  verify  - Verify an existing timestamp. Revisions without a timestamp will"
      echo "            be skipped."
      echo "  examine - Show the full text output of an existing timestamp.  Revisions"
      echo "            without a timestamp will be skipped."
      echo "  remove  - Remove an existing timestamp.  Revisions without a timestamp"
      echo "            will be skipped."
      echo "  push    - Push the timestamp namespace we're using for git notes to origin."
      echo "  fetch   - Fetch the timestamp namespace we're using for git notes from origin."
      echo
      echo " revision"
      echo "  A git revision number.  Long and short versions are accepted.  The default"
      echo "  is HEAD if no revision is specified.  Using '-' as the revision number will"
      echo "  read a rev-list from stdin and run the given command for every revision in"
      echo "  the rev-list."
      echo
      echo " warnings"
      echo "  Existing timestamps are NEVER overwritten.  It is necessary to explicitly"
      echo "  remove a timestamp with the 'remove' command if you want to replace it with"
      echo "  a newer timestamp.  There is likely nothing to be gained from removing a good"
      echo "  timestamp, so the 'remove' command should normally be used to delete corrupted"
      echo "  timestamps."
      echo
      echo " advanced examples"
      echo "  - Create timestamps for the HEAD of every branch in the 'origin' repo."
      echo "  $ git fetch && git ls-remote --heads origin | cut -f1 | git timestamp create -"
      echo
      echo "  - Get a rev-list for the origin/develop branch and verify the timestamp for"
      echo "    each revision in the list.  This is an easy way of showing every trusted"
      echo "    timestamp for a branch.  Uses the -l option to list commit timestamps too."
      echo "  $ git fetch && git rev-list origin/develop | git timestamp -l verify -"
      exit 0
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done

# Shift past all options so the command is at $1.
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

cmd="$1"

if [[ "$cmd" != "create" ]] \
    && [[ "$cmd" != "examine" ]] \
    && [[ "$cmd" != "verify" ]] \
    && [[ "$cmd" != "remove" ]] \
    && [[ "$cmd" != "push" ]] \
    && [[ "$cmd" != "fetch" ]]; then
    echo "Invalid command ${cmd}.  Try -h for usage."
    exit 1
fi

run() {
    case "$cmd" in
    create)
        create
        ;;
    examine)
        examine
        ;;
    verify)
        verify
        ;;
    remove)
        remove
        ;;
    push)
        push
        ;;
    fetch)
        fetch
        ;;
esac
}

# Shift past the given command so $1 is the revision.
shift

# If the revision argument is '-' and stdin is not empty, assume
# we're reading a rev-list from stdin and run the command for
# every revision in the list.
if [[ "$1" == "-" ]]; then
    if [ ! -z /dev/stdin ]; then
        cat /dev/stdin | while read nextrev; do
            prep "$nextrev" && isprep=true || true

            if $isprep; then
                run || one_failed=true
            fi
        done
    fi
else
    prep "$1"
    run
fi

if $one_failed; then
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [*here document*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) to avoid all those calls to `echo`:

```
cat <<END
Usage: git-timestamp [options] command [revision]

 options
  -h - Show this usage info.  All other options are ignored.
  -v - Output long revision instead of short.
  -l - Also show the local commit time of the specified revision.

 ...etc...
END
```